# View updated child-relationship information

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, standardcontroller

I got a page with standard controller and extension.

```
<apex:page id="thePage" standardcontroller="Unit__c" extensions="Unit_Ext" ....
```

Then I have blinded output field with a child relationship.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="fields" ....
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Unit__c.Tenant__r.AccountId}" ....
```

There is a dropdown field for `Tenant__c` and it re-renders above output field when changed.

```
<apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!Unit__c.Tenant__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="fields"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Tenants}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

When it rerender, `Unit__c.Tenant__c` is getting updated but `Unit__c.Tenant__r.AccountId` remain same.

How do i fix this ?

Comment: Have you queried this value - Unit__c.Tenant__r.AccountId, in controller?

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm using the standard controller. I didn't query anything

Comment: May be because both are binded to same object `Unit__c`. Try binding it to different field.

Comment: @RohitMourya Unit__c,Tenant__r,AccountId are three differnt objects

Comment: You have lookup relationship right? and `Unit__c.Tenant__r.AccountId` is retrieved by querying SOQL on `Unit__c`.

Comment: @RohitMourya With the standard controller, we can retrieve up to 5 levels in child relationships, without querying.

Comment: You are not getting what I'm trying to say. Post your controller code.

Comment: @RohitMourya the class has ApexPages.StandardController and assign record into private variable like in this sample code https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm

Comment: After the change of dropdown value, if you are not changing the value of `Unit__c.Tenant__r.AccountId`, `Unit__c.Tenant__r` to be precise, your outputField will not change. It will hold the same old value.

Comment: @SantanuHalder Exactly. That's what I was trying to convey him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this,

```
Public class OppExtention{
    public Map<id,Contact> conts { get; set;}
    public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
    public string contId {get; set;}
    public OppExtention(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        List<String> fields = new List<String>{'id','contact__c','contact__r.AccountId','contact__r.name','name'}; 
        conts = new Map<id,Contact>([Select id, name, AccountId from contact where AccountId <> null limit 5]);
        controller.addFields(fields);
        opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
      List<Selectoption> opt = new List<SelectOption>();

      for(String key: conts.keySet())
          opt.add(new SelectOption(key,conts.get(key).Name));
        return opt;
    }

    public void onChangeOption() {
        opp.contact__r.AccountId = conts.get(opp.contact__c).AccountId;
    }

}
```

---

```
 <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!opp.contact__c}" >
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="fields" action="{!onChangeOption}">
      </apex:actionSupport>
 </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: So, according to this code, If I referer more fields in Contact__c object, Do I have to query field each in conts map?

Comment: yes you need to query all the field you required.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do i have to specify all the fields of Opportunity obj. in fields list ?

Comment: Only those which are required to you